# NodeJS: Why is function being skipped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, execution

am new to nodeJs and trying to understand why in this file--app.js--the function main() never gets executed.

If I add a console.log statement before the function, it gets executed, but nothing inside the function gets executed.

I have used the debugger, and sure enough, the function is being skipped altogether.

Why is this occurring? Is there some component of node that I have overlooked?

```
'use strict';

const sendEmail = require('./send-email');

module.exports = main;

//console.log("This gets executed");

//this function never gets executed!
function main()
{
debugger
...some functionality...
}
```

Comment: how do you call your function?

Comment: If `app.js` is your entry script, Node.js doesn't use the pattern of defining a `main` function that's automatically called when executing. The entire entry script, from line 1, character 1, is the "main" code that starts your application's behavior/logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never *call* the `main` function.

Think of a function as a piece of code that is being out-sourced, and given a name. As long as you don't call it by its name, nothing will happen.

So, you need to add somewhere in your code the following line:

```
main();
```

Then it will work. (Please note that you should do this *after* declaring the `main` function.)

The `console.log` gets executed automatically, as it is not *within* a function, but already on the top-level. The same is true for the declaration of the function. That's why Node.js *creates* this function for, but you do not tell it to actually do something with it.

Actually, calling `main` will also work if done before declaring it, due to the way JavaScript handles function statements, but I'd call it better style not to do so. The same is true for using `module.exports`, this will also work this way, but I'd call it better style as well if you did it *after* creating the function.

So, to cut a long story short, your code should look like this:

```
'use strict';

const sendEmail = require('./send-email');

console.log("This gets executed");

function main()
{
  // ...
}

main();

module.exports = main;
```

This will run the `main` function for you, and export it as well (which is useful if you want to run the same function from another file).

Comment: is there a reason you moved the module.exports line to the end?

Comment: That's just personal style. Basically, you can put it anywhere in your file, but I like to have the export *always* at the bottom of the file. The logic behind this is: First define everything private, then all things public, then export them. But as said, that's just personal style.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `main` in your module but did not call `main()`. If this is all your code you need to add `main()` at the end of your code to execute it.

Answer (score -3):

> ```
> const sendEmail = require('./send-email');
> ```

… loads the module and assigns the value of `exports` to `sendEmail`.

That is **all** it does.

The value of `exports` is a function. If you want to call that function then you have to … call it.

```
sendEmail();
```